# IE wordpress nav styles perfect when logged in, but not when loggged out

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer, navigation

Out of no where, the navigation on ***site down*** started acting crazy when viewed in Internet Explorer while not logged in. However, when you log in... everything works perfectly...

I know it must be a stylesheet ordering issue, but I'm not having any luck finding a fix.

You can log in [here](http://www.childrenofallnations.com/wp-admin) with the username: *bobo* and password: *bobo*  to see what I'm talking about.

Thanks in advance for taking a look

--

EDIT

this is the jQuery for the nav:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {  
    $('#access li').each(function(){
        $(this).hover(function(){
            $('> ul',this).show();
        }, function(){
            $('> ul',this).hide();
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Wow... that's pretty crazy. Is this ALL custom? A theme? Any javascript acting on these elements?

Comment: twentlyeleven base theme with a custom child theme, and I'm pretty sure it's only the jQuery thats acting on the nav.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

I guess wordpress caught a bug when adding a new page to the menu, because after combing through the source code, I noticed one of the links closing `li` tag was out of place.

Removed that link from the nav. BAM! working perfectly now...

Hope this is able to help someone like me who feels that wordpress is out to get them.